# Trying to Import Web3 into a react application

Tags: web3js, react

If I just run npm install web3 I get a bunch of errors

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert'
....etc.
```

If I run npm install or npm install dependencies I get the same result.

I stumbled across another question that the answer said to change the import statement to

```js
import Web3 from 'https://cdn.esm.sh/v58/web3@1.6.1/es2021/web3.js';
```

Which works in development....but when I turn it into a build package to deploy it
"The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script"

If I make a local file called web3 with the content from the cdn link from above I get the same "Can't resolve" errors as in the first situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently with a particular version of React this can be an issue. Currently with the most recent version 17.0.2 I'm having no issues.
So if anyone else runs into this I'd say try a different version of react.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install ethereum/web3.js
```

That should install your missing dependencies and compile properly

Answer (score 0):

here is what you should do:

console:

```
npm i web3
```

index.js

```
const Web3 = require("web3")
const web3 = new Web3(<RPC provider link>)
```